# What does わせ in this sentence mean?

Tags: words, causation, old-japanese

> なぜ死なしてしもたか、人生を狂る**わせ**たのか

Does this sentence contain typo? I guess 狂るわせ should be 狂わせ.

What do you guys think?

Comment: The title of your question is asking the meaning of わせ, and the body is just about whether 狂るわせ is a typo. Which did you intend to ask? Both?

Answer (score 3):

It would be regarded as a typo if interpreted as standard contemporary Japanese. However, the usage of okurigana was not standardized 100 years ago as it is today, and you would frequently encounter such eye-catching usages of okurigana when reading old novels. So, if this is a quote from a novel written 100 years ago, for example, I would probably regard 狂るわせた as a kanji usage that was acceptable for that time.